# What are the Arduino hardware options for experimenting with IoT?

Tags: wifi, iot, ble

Just starting to learn about Arduino and IoT. I'd like to know what the Arduino hardware options are to try the following:

1. Use FreeRTOS as SO
2. WiFi and BLE connectivity
3. Solderless board
4. Test OTA features
5. Experiment integration with different IoT Cloud platforms e.g. Azure IoT Hub
6. Build custom IoT devices

Comment: an opinion based question, but ESP32 is the answer

Comment: One of the options for closing a question is that it's "opinion-based" and you're asking for what "is best".  Without any criteria on what you mean by "best" it's difficult to say that the question won't get closed for that reason.

Comment: Thank you @Juraj and @ timemage for your comments! Both of you are precise on the option-based question. The reason is that as there are so many options available at the Arduino store am not clear which of them would allow me to do all the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options; which one is "best" for you I leave up to your own research, that could start here:

There's a list of Arduino's based on the SAMD21 that are supported by the [FreeRTOS_SAMD21](https://github.com/BriscoeTech/Arduino-FreeRTOS-SAMD21) library [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/freertos_samd21/); pick any one with WiFi and BLE.

There are probably a zillion clones out there that could also do what you want, and there is also a FreeRTOS port for the ESP32 (ESP-IDF FreeRTOS, and maybe other ones as well).

Comment: Thank you @ocrdu

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer (if you accept the answer) so the question doesn't stay open.